# GPO install Live Meeting 2007 on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy

Errors:

> The removal of the assignment of application Microsoft Office Live
>   Meeting 2007 from policy LiveMeeting 2007 failed. The error was : %%2
>
> The description for Event ID 103 from source Application Management
>   Group Policy cannot be found. Either the component that raises
>
> this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation
>   is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local
>   computer.

We've got problems only on Windows 8.1 domain stations ...
Windows 7 domain stations dont have problems with it

Checked:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bcf38d47-c4b6-4355-a79f-1f256bbed933/can-not-push-software-via-group-policy

http://mywinsysadm.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/windows-7-the-assignment-of-application-from-policy-failed-the-error-was/

and without success ...

Manuall install works fine : Live Meeting x86  with Windows 8.1 x64

Anyone have idea whats going on with GPO ???

Comment: I thought MS EOL'd LiveMeeting years ago?

Comment: @TheCleaner Not entirely, they keep publishing patches and compatability fixes for Windows >6.2 and Office 2013

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - interesting.  I remember when we were using LiveMeeting and MS themselves sent us notice that we wouldn't be able to use their Online services for meetings anymore after some specific date at least 3 years ago and to start using Lync Online meetings instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying install Office Live Meeting 2007 on Windows 8.1 by workarround via batch file similar like deploy Office 2013 ...

SO I have:

```
@echo off
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%ProductName%
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto DeployLiveMeeting) else (goto End)
REM If 1 returned, the product was not found. Run setup here.
:DeployLiveMeeting
start /wait msiexec.exe /i \\scripts\OfficeCommunicator2007\LiveMeeting.msi" /passive /norestart
REM If 0 or other was returned, the product was found or another error occurred. Do nothing.
:End
```

But %ProductName% at the end of reg query (Office15.PROPLUS) worked on Office 2013 ...  - what i should use for Live Meeting ???